# Regex without taking care of escape codes

Tags: c#, regex, string, parsing, encoding

I want to validate a string like this (netsh cmd output):

```
"\r\nR‚servations d'URLÿ:\r\n--------------------\r\n\r\n    URL r‚serv‚e            : https://+:443/SomeWebSite/ \r\n        Utilisateurÿ: AUTORITE NT\\SERVICE R\u0090SEAU\r\n            \u0090couterÿ: Yes\r\n            D‚l‚guerÿ: Yes\r\n            SDDLÿ: D:(A;;GA;;;NS) \r\n\r\n\r\n"
```

with this pattern:

```
"URL .+https:\/\/\+:443\/SomeWebSite\/.+Yes.+Yes.+SDDL.+"
```

So, I intend to detect this kind of strings (xxxxx is something(+)):

```
xxxxxURLxxxxxhttps://+:443/SomeWebSite/xxxxxYesxxxxxYesxxxxxSDDLxxxx
```

I wrote this code in C# to do it but my expression still doesn't work:

```
string output = "\r\nR‚servations d'URLÿ:\r\n--------------------\r\n\r\n    URL r‚serv‚e            : https://+:443/SomeWebSite/ \r\n        Utilisateurÿ: AUTORITE NT\\SERVICE R\u0090SEAU\r\n            \u0090couterÿ: Yes\r\n            D‚l‚guerÿ: Yes\r\n            SDDLÿ: D:(A;;GA;;;NS) \r\n\r\n\r\n";
output = output.Replace(Environment.NewLine, ""); //==> output2=="R‚servations d'URLÿ:-----------
Regex testUrlOpened = new Regex(output, RegexOptions.Singleline);
MessageBox.Show(testUrlOpened.IsMatch(@"URL").ToString()); // ==> False
MessageBox.Show(testUrlOpened.IsMatch(@".+URL.+").ToString()); // ==> False
MessageBox.Show(testUrlOpened.IsMatch(@"URL .+https:\/\/\+:443\/SomeWebSite\/.+Yes.+Yes.+SDDL.+").ToString()); // ==> False
```

So I suppose that I've another issue with regex in c#...
May be encoding issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start by removing the escape codes expected in the string . It might be better to remove them all depending on your use scenario [(C# escape codes)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h21280bw.aspx)

```
output = output.Replace('\n').Replace('\r').Replace('\t')
```

Now you have a single line string, you can do the regex matching

```
.+URL.+https:\/\/.+:443\/SomeWebSite\/.+Yes.+Yes.+SDDL.+
```

Notice the following:
1- the ^ and $ means to match the exact begin and end of the string. If you have the target string within the line using these will cause the matching to fail.

2- You need to escape the necessary regex characters .
3- To match "Any character except new line one or more times" you use .+

I hope this helps

Comment: Hi Moataz, thanks for your help... Two many years since my last regex ... :)

Comment: Welcome. You may want to use : http://regexr.com/ . I find it very helpful in debugging and understanding my regex expressions.

Comment: Do not rely on regexr for testing .NET regexes, it does not support .NET regex syntax. Check `[\w-[_]]+` at regexr and [regexstorm](http://regexstorm.net/tester) with `new_word`

Comment: But finally, I've another issue... Even pattern ".+URL.+" doesn't match... I've edited my original question...

Comment: Got it... I've swapped input and regexpr... :(

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Regex.Unescape` to unescape the string, and then do your regex match :

```
var output = @"\r\nR‚servations d'URLÿ:\r\n--------------------\r\n\r\n    URL r‚serv‚e            : https://+:443/SomeWebSite/ \r\n        Utilisateurÿ: AUTORITE NT\\SERVICE R\u0090SEAU\r\n            \u0090couterÿ: Yes\r\n            D‚l‚guerÿ: Yes\r\n            SDDLÿ: D:(A;;GA;;;NS) \r\n\r\n\r\n";
output = Regex.Unescape(output).Dump();

var foundUrl = Regex.IsMatch(output, @"URL .+ https://\+:443/SomeWebSite/.+YES.+YES.+SDDL.+");
```

Answer (score 0):

`+` indicates 1 or more of the previously stated pattern, if we put the pattern `(.|\n)`, which matches **anything**, in front of those `+`'s, you'll be all set, without having to remove or account for escape codes.

`^(.|\n)+URL(.|\n)+https://(.|\n)+:443/SomeWebSite/(.|\n)+Yes(.|\n)+Yes(.|\n)+SDDL(.|\n)+$`

EDIT: The risk of doing something like this instead of sanitizing your string first is that you may get false positives because there could be any character separating the matches, all this regex does is ensure that somewhere in the string, in order, are the strings

```
"URL", "https://", ":443/SomeWebSite/", "Yes", "Yes", "SDDL"
```

Comment: Thanks, easier in my opinion to delete "\r\n" in input string but interesting idea.

Answer (score 0):

So simple. Last issue was due to reg expression to put in Regex constructor and input string in IsMatch Method... :(
So final code is:

```
string output = "\r\nR‚servations d'URLÿ:\r\n--------------------\r\n\r\n    URL r‚serv‚e            : https://+:443/SomeWebSite/ \r\n        Utilisateurÿ: AUTORITE NT\\SERVICE R\u0090SEAU\r\n            \u0090couterÿ: Yes\r\n            D‚l‚guerÿ: Yes\r\n            SDDLÿ: D:(A;;GA;;;NS) \r\n\r\n\r\n";
output = output.Replace(Environment.NewLine, ""); //==> output2=="R‚servations d'URLÿ:-----------
Regex testUrlOpened = new Regex((@"URL .+https:\/\/\+:443\/SomeWebSite\/.+Yes.+Yes.+SDDL.+", RegexOptions.Singleline);
MessageBox.Show(testUrlOpened.IsMatch(output).ToString()); // ==> True!!!
```

Answer (score -1):

Regex taking decimal number only without using escape character.

```
^[0-9]+([.][0-9]+)?$
```

[Test It](https://regex101.com/)